# High resolution bitmap causes OutOfMemoryError exception, already set largeHeap=true

Tags: android, bitmap, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I already tried,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Still giving following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 552960012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 262MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
```

I am using a gridView and putting adapter with integer array of drawable's resourceId in it, but some of the high resolution images in my drawable array are causing this issue.

Comment: Maybe your device didn't have 553MB of free memory in that moment.

Comment: in any case you won't be able to effectively use such a large image. LOad it pre-scaled

Answer (score 0):

try to add below code in your build.gradle(Module:app) in android { ... } it will help you little bit or else you can low down to quality at time of image load.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific with the file and it's location? i mean where to put it in the file code?

Answer (score 0):

downscale image into your drawable folder. Decrees drawable resolution before placing it into drawable folder. also here is online site where you can decrees size of your image without losing image resolution. [Link1](https://tinypng.com/) and [Link2](https://tinyjpg.com/)

Answer (score 0):

@Hafeezulhaq  in build.gradle(Module:app) file,file located in Gradle Scripts section in it you can put this above mention code under android { ...  } section in file. [image]

Comment: Process: com.wallpapers.footballActorsBlack, PID: 3572
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 46612492 byte allocation with 9626520 free bytes and 9MB until OOM

Answer (score 0):

you must convert the high resolution of your drawable image to: `drawable-xxhdpi`. 
and add: `android:largeHeap="true"` on `androidManifest.xml`

I have solved my OutOfMemory problem by using this method